# альтернатива событию PointerPressed / обработчик событий

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, properties

изучаю C# Э.Стиллмен, Дж.Грин  (Head First O'Reilly) - 2014
Многое приходится заменять и это радует, остановилась на Событии для кнопки, которая должна по идее при зажатии перемещать объект .

Но **у меня PointerPressed нету** и хочу узнать. **Каким другим (семейством) события  для мышки можно заменить?** 
UPD. пролистала там еще много таких из семейства Pointer. 
[image]

Comment: `MouseDown`?...

Comment: Вам нужно перетаскивать объекты по канве? Посмотрите этот вопрос, там есть рабочий код https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6143072/drag-and-drop-shapes